# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hello everyone when i'm compile my app in prod release i got an error

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select'.

My code

```
<ion-select #sel1  [(ngModel)]="Selectedcat" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" >
```

i make this configuration in appmodule :

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 HttpModule,
 Ionic2RatingModule ,
 FormsModule,
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
 IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
 IonicImageLoader.forRoot()
 ]
```

thanks for yours help

Comment: Does it work in non-prod mode?

Comment: By the way, why do you use ``(ngModelChange)`` and not ``(ionChange)``?

Comment: yes in non-prod I don't have any error and everythink work. By the way I use it in component

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

the problem was because I use in a component so you need to add in components.modules.ts 
    imports: [IonicModule],

that's all

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to components modules

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  IonicModule,
  FormsModule
 ];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Simply, import the above (`FormsModule`) module in your modules page it will work!