# How to bind select or ion-select ? FormsModule included

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to bind a simple select or a ion-select, but for now, It's just not working...

I have imported FormsModule in module and page:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

but still getting the same error :

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select'.
```

Here is the view :

```
<ion-list>
<ion-list-header>Choix du jeu</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Mode de jeu</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gameMode" placeholder="choix...">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let s of games" value="{{s}}">{{s}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

(ngFor is working)

My module.ts file :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {ScoreModalComponent} from './score-modal/score-modal.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ScoreModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [ScoreModalComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
            IonicModule.forRoot(),
            IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
            AppRoutingModule,
            FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can I see your module.ts?

Comment: I see you have imported the `FormsModule` in a module, which is good. Did you add that to the `imports` array in the module, too?

Comment: Can't put all the module.ts file into comment :(...
I add it to the array module, yes !

Comment: Does the application compile, and run?

Comment: I add module.ts code into my first post.
 Compiled successfully, yes, but not running (it run if I delete ngModel of ion-select)

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674657/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ion-select

Comment: run it on ionic 4 worked fine maybe you need to update you ionic angular version ?

Comment: Need more help with this solution @R.Richards please ?
I'm on ionic 4 with angular 7 !

Comment: Did you try adding `FormsModule` to the module file for the page component you are working with?

Comment: It's working !!! 1 day lost on this problem ! Thank you so much ! Can you explain me why it's needed to import FormsModule everywhere like this ?

Comment: It seems to be the way Ionic likes it. Modules are meant to isolate code like this, so it make sense (but it can be frustrating).

Comment: It is ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

In ion-list documentation, there isn't any two-way binding. but there is event binding `(click)`